# How to migrate this old table to these new two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I'm dealing with the following situation: I have a table of customers, on which the addresses of the customers are saved as columns on each row.

Now, after a redesign, there is now a table `Addresses` for the addresses and the customer table references the address.

In migrating to this new structure, I first migrated the customers to the new table, leaving the `AddressId` column `NULL`.

Then I've set out to migrate the addresses. First, the code I have in mind is:

```
INSERT INTO Addresses (
    Address,
    City,
    State
) SELECT 
    Address,
    City,
    State
FROM OldDatabase.dbo.Customers
```

Now, the problem is that for each insert performed there, for each address taken from the old customer table to the new one, the address id must be added to the corresponding customer row in the customer table.

How can I do this? How can I, for each of these inserts, add the reference, by setting the `AddressId` of the corresponding customer to the address id just added?

**EDIT**: The new customer table has a lot of fields, for the purpose of the question we can consider it has the fields:

- CustomerId,
- AddressId

The addresses table has the fields

- AddressId,
- Address,
- City,
- State

The old customer table was just all of this together:

- CustomerId,
- Address,
- City,
- State

I need to migrate this old structure to the new one. So I need to map each customer entry of this old table, to a new customer entry *plus* one address entry.

I tried first migrating all the customers, leaving the `AddressId` null, to later on migrate the addresses but it's not working as expected, because if I migrate the addresses as I'm trying, I don't know how to add the relation.

Comment: Please add your tables structure and the expected result

Comment: @Sami, I've added some more details to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the AddressID that you're getting from the insert and update the Customers table with it. The below is a little fast and loose (i.e. no error handling), but presents the basic idea.

```
declare @Addresses table (AddressID int)
begin tran

    INSERT INTO Addresses (
        Address,
        City,
        State
    ) 
    output Inserted.AddressID into @Addresses
    SELECT 
        Address,
        City,
        State
    FROM OldDatabase.dbo.Customers

    where CustomerID = @CustomerID;

    update OldDatabase.dbo.Customers
    set AddressID = (select top(1) AddressID from @Addresses)

commit tran
```

If you're doing this in a loop over Customers, make sure to clear out the @Addresses table between customers (otherwise every Customer record will get the same AddressID!)